# Why does the CAN bus need termination resistors and other buses don't?

Tags: can, bus

I've been working on a project based on CAN bus communication. In the past, I also worked on projects with other high-speed buses, for example SPI. Although SPI is a high-speed bus it does not need any resistors and reflections do not occur.

Why does the CAN bus need termination resistors to work properly and other buses don't.?

Comment: Who says other buses don't? Most do. SPI bus might need termination too, maybe just somewhat different kind than CAN. There is also great difference if the bus is 0.1 meters or 100 meters in length.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But why for example even short CAN bus cables (let's say 50 cm) in theory needs termination resistors.

Comment: A SPI bus usually is terminated, just in a different way that is determined by the particular scenario. It might not even be obvious that it is terminated to the casual observer.

Comment: I can tell you that we had some 13 years ago a 25MHz SPI with roughly 10cm length. The App Note of the Manufacturer suggested a series resistor in the clock for impedance matching... we spend days until with a >2GHz Scope + active probe we detected a reproducible glitch after some 10k clock cycles... another - not suggested - resistor in the data lines fixed that to. So even a slow SPI may need a matched impedance [Edited by a moderator.]

Answer (score 6):

CAN bus won't work at all without termination resistors, because the resistors keep the bus lines at same voltage (0V differential) when they are not driven by any transmitter.

So even a CAN bus of 10cm needs termination resistors, to have correct current and voltage on the bus when driven and not driven.

That's because CAN is a differential open-drain / open-collector bus, where bus lines float at recessive state unless being actively driven by a transmitter, and the transmitter will only drive CANH high and CANL low, creating a differential voltage between bus wires, and making current flow via termination resistors.

As the termination resistors are located at both ends of the bus wiring, they also prevent reflections from happening at the end of the bus.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of more complicated transmission lines that CAN is intended for and that SPI wasn't intended for. And its changed for SPI over time.

CAN is a multi-drop multi-master bus designed for inter-board communications through cables and over distances: up to 40 m at 1 Mbps, further when slower. It uses unbalanced differential signalling and the termination resistance is required to develop the signalling voltage.

SPI is a single-master bus intended for short-distance communications over tracks within a board to specific target devices. Its signalling is TTL and its lower-voltage derivatives. Its speed increased over the years which has led to series termination resistors being used for over, say, 20 MHz or so.